# strange Debugging Error: possible memory corruption?

Tags: c++, eclipse, gdb

I've got a strange problem:
I use eclipse and have written a program which is quite long. Now if I compile "Debug" (so no compiler optimization) and click "Run" then everything is finde and my Program produces the expected output.
Now If I compile "Release" the program does not terminate but instead "stops" at one point...

So I've started Debugging with the dgb Debugger build into eclipse and clicked through the program. And if I let it just run through everything is fine, but If I click through every single line of code then the program "stops" at some other point.

Now I've gone one step further and clicked not only through every line but stepped into each function.

What I found very strange is that in depence on HOW I step through my program with the debugger I get the error at different positions. So I think the stopping of the debugger is related to eclipse which cannot show something in the debugger-window or so.
Additionally the error critically depends on other lines of code.
So my best guess is that the error is related to some memory problem.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Is `this` NULL or is `this->_M_impl` NULL?

Comment: It is indeed necessary to produce an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org). Why? because what you describe sounds a lot like undefined behavior, which often stems from errors committed somwhere *before* they seem to appear. In addition, if you try to reduce the code to narrow down the problem you often find enough hints to solve it yourself.

Comment: Yeah! I will do this. But it gets even stranger... The Debugger stops at some point but I think I located the error at some point AFTER this. Could this be? The Release configuration runs up to this point and then stops. EDIT: Ignore this... I dont understand what is happening :D

Comment: Sadly I'm not able to make an SSCCE. Could it be that vector<string>  makes problems? And that something like push_back("test"); on an vector<string> can cause memory problems?